# What search terms can you use with Valve search?

Tags: full-text-search

Self-answer. I'm answering this to help other people looking for the semantics of the DSL.

The engine is elasticsearch, so it's a superset of the elasticsearch vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of search terms, so I've broken them up into ones that filter based on (1) time, (2) request, and (3) response.

### Time

`date:` search a specific day. Like: `date:2021-06-19`

`before:` date, datetime, or duration from now. Like: `before:"2021-06-19 11:23:27"`

`after:` date, datetime, or duration from now. Like: `after:"2021-06-19 11:23:27"`

`last:` duration from now, like `last:"2 hours"` (alias `younger_than`)

`ago:` duration from now, like `ago:"1 day"` (alias `older_than`)

### Request

`method:` case-insensitive [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

`domain:` a string like `example.com`

`path:` a string like `/example/path`

`request_header:` like `request_header:"Host: example.com"`

`request_body:` full body text search

### Response

`status:` a numeric status like `200`, a string [reason](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html) like `ok` or `"Gateway Timeout"`, or the keywords `success` (status < 400), or `error` (status >= 400)

`response_header:` like like `request_header:"X-Cache: HIT"`

`response_body:` full body text search

### Addendum: Headers

Capitalized terms are interpreted as headers, like `Host:example.com`. This searches both request headers and response headers.